# Can I create RESTFUL Web services in Spring 3.0 without MVC

Tags: php, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Currently building a "Business Layer", that serves up JSON to a PHP application. Considering using Spring with growth of the application in mind.

All my research so far leads me to believe that restful web services are only possible in an MVC context. Since my front end (display tier) is not Java MVC does not make sense.

Am I missing  anything or this a limitation of Spring WS ? If thats the case then what are the other possible alternatives ? Jersey/Restlet for JAX-RS ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you can't use Spring MVC for your REST services.   It would work just as well as JAX-RS.

As long as you use [mvc:annotation-driven](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven) and Jackson is on the classpath then all you should need to do is use `@ResponseBody` on your controller methods and the return type will be converted to JSON per Spring's standard [HTTP Message Conversion](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-message-conversion) functionality.

Also check out this video at around 37:00: [Mastering Spring MVC](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Mastering-Spring-MVC-3).

Comment: yes, but I dont want to build servlet controllers and such for this app. I want to be able to write a standalone Java app and expose it as a service. Is Spring MVC a good candidate ?

Comment: Ah, you mean you don't want to have to run it in Servlet container?

Comment: If you don't want to run it in a Servlet container (eg Tomcat) then Spring MVC is not an option.